# Strange thing with CommonJS recursive importing

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I don't know where is problem: in JavaScript VM or in something else... but in this simple program

m.js

```
console.log("main", require("./m1"));
```

m1.js

```
var M = require('./m2');

exports.m = {
    m2: M.m,
    test: "m1"
}
```

m2.js

```
var M = require('./m1');

exports.m = {
    m1: M.m,
    test: "m2"
}

console.log("m2", M);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("m2 nexttick", M);
}, 0);
```

i get a strange output.

```
m2 {}
main { m: { m2: { m1: undefined, test: 'm2' }, test: 'm1' } }
m2 nexttick { m: { m2: { m1: undefined, test: 'm2' }, test: 'm1' } }
```

Can someone explain this? Why object is populated asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fake version of the require function, to illustrate why this is occurring.

When you call `require` on a module, it creates an empty module in cache.  Then, it attempts to evaluate the module.  If you require another module from that one, and that other module `require`s the original module, it will get the empty module, since the first module *hasn't finished evaluating*.

My answer here is very limited, but you can find entire articles about **circular dependencys**.

```
var cache = { };
function require(moduleName) {
    if ( cache.hasOwnProperty(moduleName) )
        return cache[moduleName]
    cache[moduleName] = undefined;
    cache[moduleName] = evaluate( moduleName );
}
```